# Finding nice representation for a partial geometric sum

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, geometric-series

Everyone knows that (when $x<1$) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$.

I was wondering if one can find a simple expression (i.e. without the sum) of $\sum_{n \in \langle p_1,...,p_k\rangle} x^{n}$ where $\langle p_1,...,p_k\rangle$ denotes the set of all integers whose prime divisors are only those $k$ primes.

---

I considered the simplest example: $\langle p\rangle$ and that already made me stuck:
$\sum_{n \in \langle p\rangle} x^{n} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{p^m}= ???$.

**I should say that I just came up with this question and that the $\langle \rangle$ sign was made up for the sake of the question and is not a standard writing.

Comment: There almost surely isn't a nice formula for this restricted sum. For multiplicatively defined sets $S$, power series $\sum_{n\in S} x^n$ aren't that nice, but Dirichlet series $\sum_{n\in S} n^{-s}$ are very nice.

Comment: @GregMartin - I would love to see a nice formula for such series if you could write it. But also, what makes you so sure there isn't a nice formula for the sum I defined?